# SQL QUERY dont start at 1

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I got an sql query and it does is it stores data on the table. which its start with the number. Is there any possible way that this script when i run it. it wont start on number 1.

> ---
>
> MISSING
>         1
>         2
>         3
>         4
>         5

And this is what i want

> ---
>
> MISSING
>         12
>         13
>         14
>         15
>         16

```
SELECT IDENTITY(INT,@parameter, 1) Missing
      INTO dbo.tally
      FROM master.sys.all_columns c
      CROSS JOIN master.sys.all_columns c1
```

Comment: Is @parameter assigned a value of 11?\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to generate number. You can do this:

```
WITH Nbrs ( n ) AS (
        SELECT 12 UNION ALL
        SELECT 1 + n FROM Nbrs WHERE n < 16 )
SELECT 
   n AS MISSING 
FROM 
   Nbrs
```

**Update**

There are numbers of way that you can do a tally table. The most common case it using a loop to generate the number

This example shows a tally table that is generate using a recursive CTE. The first part:

```
SELECT 12 UNION ALL
```

Defines were you want to start the tally table. The second part:

```
SELECT 1 + n FROM Nbrs WHERE n < 16 )
```

Defines were to end the tally table. If you would remove the `WHERE n < 16` then would continue generating numbers forever. Or it would trow a maxrecursive error. In the second part we also define how much we want to increse the number with `SELECT 1 + n`. If you would change it to `SELECT 2 + n`. Then the output would look like this:

```
MISSING
12
14
16
```

Now because we increase the tally table with `SELECT 1 + n` and stop it at 16. The output will be:

```
MISSING
12
13
14
15
16
```

**Update 2**

If you want to have more numbers then 300k. Then you can just set:

```
OPTION ( MAXRECURSION 0 )
```

in the button of the query. So for example this:

```
WITH Nbrs ( n ) AS (
        SELECT 12 UNION ALL
        SELECT 1 + n FROM Nbrs WHERE n < 1000000000 )
SELECT 
   n AS MISSING 
FROM 
   Nbrs
OPTION ( MAXRECURSION 0 )
```

will generate more then 300k. I think this error was introduced so you can't have recursive ctes that never ends.

References:

- [Recursive Queries Using Common Table Expressions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
- [Creating Tally Tables using CTE in SQL Server 2005/2008](http://blogs.inkeysolutions.com/2011/05/creating-tally-tables-using-cte-in-sql.html)
- [SQL Server Error Messages - Msg 310 - The value  specified for the MAXRECURSION option exceeds the allowed maximum of 32767.](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-310.aspx)

Comment: no idea about this code do.. :D.. can u guide me through this code.. :D

Comment: ...question.. this answer is only good for 32k cursion..what if i deal with.. let say maximum of 300k maximum..is there any way